# AWS Lambda function redirection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need help in AWS Lambda function redirection.
I have AWS Lambda Api endpoint url as below
    https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west.amazonaws.com/api/updatestats/click?url=yahoo.com

Now after executing the code of above AWS Lambda api, i want to get the value of query param "url" and redirect the lambda api endpoint url to the url i.e yahoo.com

Please let me know if any one have idea about this.

Thanks
Raju

Comment: This can be accomplished using integration response mapping.  You need to have your Lambda function return the location of the redirect and then define the mapping to use that in the ``Location`` header of the ``30x`` HTTP response.  See this blog for details (https://rpgreen.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/how-to-http-redirects-with-api-gateway-and-lambda/)

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the valuable information.
I want to handle the redirection in python Lambda Function and i'm not able to find proper solution.
If you have any idea please share the info.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with the following code in your lambda function:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  context.succeed({location: 'https://example.com'});
};
```

More details are described here:
https://kennbrodhagen.net/2016/04/02/how-to-return-302-using-api-gateway-lambda/

Comment: you sure that's python code ??